# How do I resolve jstl errors when upgrading Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jstl

I'm trying to upgrade Spring Boot from version 2.1.x to 2.2.x, but keep getting issues with jstl includes in my jsp files.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I have these dependencies in my gradle setup

```
dependencies {
    // Spring Boot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // Web
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.40'
```

And in my jsp file I have these includes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" session="false" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
```

It has all been working when using Spring Boot version 2.1.x, but as soon as I use 2.2.x it breaks with the error described above.

When I start the application I use this VM option in my IntelliJ setup

```
-Dtomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=jstl*.jar,spring-webmvc*.jar
```

I do not have a web.xml file but instead I have a web.config file which we use when deploying in Azure. But that should not be relevant when testing it locally...

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? And why is Spring Boot 2.2.x breaking this when I can't find anything in the release notes about any breaking changes related to jsp or jstl?

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you deploying your application to? In case you are actually deploying it into a Tomcat server in Azure, you should mark the tomcat-embedded-jasper dependency as provided

```
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.40'
```

Comment: As of now I have it set like this: implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.40', the only dependency I have as provided runtime is: providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

Comment: Set that first one as providedRuntime. Then you should actually deploy it to a Tomcat server.

Comment: When changing to providedRuntime for that dependency I get an error: `error: package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;` When I add that dependency (javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.2) it works (using Spring Boot 2.1.18). But when I update to version 2.2.0 and then build I get this error: `Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException at ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156`, so basically my tests start to fail. Any idea what needs to be updated to fix this, is there something I need to add in the dependency list related to the tests?

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException at ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156
: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException at TomcatWebServer.java:126
: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException at ContainerBase.java:928
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException at FutureTask.java:122
: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException at ContainerBase.java:928
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException at FutureTask.java:122
: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException at LifecycleBase.java:440
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at TldRuleSet.java:54`